# Match with mask algorithm

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching

I have a set of rules that consist of value/mask. E.g:

```
(1) value = 0x01010100 mask = 0xffffff00
(2) value = 0x02020200 mask = 0xffffff00
(3) value = 0x01010100 mask = 0x01010100
```

And given an input value X I want to find the set of all rules that match.

For example for X = 0x01010101 I should get (1), (3) since

```
0x01010101 & 0xffffff00 == 0x01010100 (match (1))
```

and

```
0x01010101 & 0x01010100 == 0x01010100 (match (3))
```

What is the best data-structure/algorithm I can use?

Thanks!

Comment: It would helpful if you would at least provide a solution if you down vote the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be done using a DFA but with a subtlety.  If this were simply match a bit string against a bunch of predefined bit strings then this would be a regular grammar

```
(0x01010100 | 0x02020200 | 0x01010100)
```

would equate to the binary regular expressions

```
("00000001000000010000000100000000"|"00000010000000100000001000000000"| etc...
```

this is a regular expression because it's a finite set of literal binary strings so since the language is regular, then the minimal machine to accept it is a DFA, but the bit mask makes it more difficult, however, it can be overcome with the following insight.  The DFA that results from the above grammar can be augmented to a nondeterministic DFA (NDFA) with the following behavior.

If the NDFA reaches a state S where if the input takes it to state X0 if the input string is a 0 and X1 if then input string is a 1, then allow the NDFA to branch to both states X0 and X1 simultaneously if the mask is 0 (i.e. the input is processed as if it's simultaneously 0 and 1 at the same time).

Now, the theoretic result is that every NDFA [has an equivalent DFA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton), so the above can be re-written as a DFA (with more states of course, however that's all done as a pre-processing step.

Thus a DFA can be constructed that will with at most 32 bitwise comparisons evaluate any input string against all possible rules.

A possible data structure would support representing a general directed graph (nodes and edges), or even more efficiently, a program would be generated like Lex does where it's all code connected with switch statements.